# How to know what user is used by a "command git push" invoked by job jenkins

Tags: windows, git, powershell, jenkins, gitlab

I have developed a **powershell script for update a git repository** with a directory content generated by an external process.

Script is executed by a **job jenkins**, allocated in a Jenkins Windows Server. Job has a **generic gitlab connection** to corporate repository server.

Script powershell uses **git command line** (like git clone, git branch, git push…) and it does the task well, updating remote repository correctly.

The problem is… **I don't know what credentials are used to interact with git repository when I call git push**… Git push don't ask a user and password, and it does the work well.

The question.  **Is there any way to know what user is used by command git push?.** I guess it uses the job jenkins' gitlab connection but i must ensure it.

Thanks a lot,
Alfonso Martín.

Comment: powershell knows the unix commad `whoami` (= who am I) which outputs `domain/user_name`

Answer (score 1):

Since the jenkins job triggers a powershell script, the script would be executed with the user with which jenkins process is running. I am guessing this ID (system id which runs jenkins) has a ssh key setup in gitlab and connects without password.

You may add `git config user.name` to your powershell script to print the user name.

The system powershell script execution would not have access to jenkins gitlab profile to push code. That would be jenkins job checkout or posting from jenkins itself.

Comment: Upvoted, but, the `user.name` setting is only used when making new commits. A `git push` never looks at it. (In other words that one sentence in the middle is not really helpful, I think.)

Comment: Thank you @torek. The `user.name` line is there to answer the question - Is there any way to know what user is used by command git push?

As stated by you push won't use it but if put in the same powershell script where push is happening, we can list the user name git is configured with.

Comment: Ah, I understand now: you're suggesting that someone first figure out what user name is actually used, then that this same person set `user.name` to report the name figured out in the first step. That's reasonable enough, but somewhat fragile: if for some reason the name actually used changes, the configured string won't.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ace. Unfortunately the solution proposed doesn't works. That´s the situation:

I have checked it locally, putting (git config user.name) in the powershell, and executing in my local machine, and it works fine, showing me actual windows user.
When i deploy the script to be executed by jenkins, this line doesn't show anything.

Any idea about that?

Thanks…

Alf.

Comment: Trying to list user.name would only print something if one has been set before. 

I would think may be in this there is not one set. May be you can check by invoking the command in command line for the user which is executing the powershell to be sure.